# LMC assemble code n- bit binary to decimal

Tags: little-man-computer

I am trying to create an LMC assemble code that can convert an n-bit binary number into a number using the base-10 number system. Display the natural number as an output before halting the program.

Comment: *"I am trying to create..."*: please include in your question what you have tried. Explain what the specific problem is that you encountered. Please provide sample input, expected output, and what your attempt produces instead for that sample input (or which error you get). Also specify which simulator you are using to test your code (since there are different flavours of LMC).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert n-bit binary to base 10 number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66992045/convert-n-bit-binary-to-base-10-number)